# error trying to use boost c++ library in R

Tags: c++, r, boost

I'm using an R script that calls compiled C++ code to solve ODEs numerically using the deSolve R Package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deSolve/vignettes/compiledCode.pdf

I want to use the boost/parameter function in C++. So I installed boost and have the lines

```
#include <boost/parameter/name.hpp>
#include <boost/parameter/preprocessor.hpp>
#include <string>
```

in my .c file.

However when I try to  compile the c++ code from my R script using

```
system("R CMD SHLIB kh.c")
```

I get the error message

> "C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.0/include"
>   -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c kh.c -o kh.o kh.c:6:36: fatal error: boost/parameter/name.hpp: No such file or
>   directory  #include "

If I don't use boost then I can get the C++ code to work (i.e. the numerical solver works and C++ is being called correctly), it just seems to be boost that is the problem

How do I help R find boost?

Comment: Side note that may help but could be totally unrelated: .c files are usually C code. .cpp are usually C++ code. I only mention because I have had a IDE get confused before because it was mid-labeled. Your situation could be completely different, though.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue as it works fine if I dont try to include boost

Comment: I'm not R savvy. Have you tried to add to the R flag `CPPFLAGS=-I/path/to/boost`. I'm watching as I intend to install R one of these days.